# Prepending a common logo to the Product Title in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When a single product is viewed, it would show the title, description of the product, etc.

So what I am trying to do is, to implement a hook for the `woocommerce_page_title` (got it from [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/)), so that I could prepend the html code for the logo in that text.

But it seems to be not working. The code I have tried is as follows:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_page_title',
'isa_product_title_heading');

function isa_product_title_heading($content) {
    $abctemp = '<img src="'.home_url('/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/mysite_logo.400_jpg.jpg').'" />' . $content;
    //echo $abctemp; die;
    return __($abctemp, 'woocommerce');
}
```

[image]

In this figure, the yellow portion is where I am trying to insert the logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any image or text to the template directly or using wordpress hooks.

1. Template way:
   Create this file structure in your wordpress template foler:

   ```
   |
   L templatename
     L woocommerce
       L single-product
         L title.php
   ```

Insert this code to the title.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product title
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

?>
<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">
    <img src="your_image.jpg">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</h1>
```

2.The second way is to use this code sample somewhere in your functions.php or in your plugin

```
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_template_single_title', 5);
    function custom_template_single_title() {
        global $product;
        echo '<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">'
             . '<img src="your_image.jpg">' 
             . $product->get_title() 
             . '</h1>';
    }
```

I'd reccomend to use the first way. But if you're developing a plugin, of course, you shouldn't edit templates anyway

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I used the second method and it worked flawlessly. :)